# Group all the message by username like Facebook does

Tags: php, mysql, sql, facebook

Okay, After few hours of coding I have end up with this code and am stuck here. What I' am trying to do is, if you goto your Facebook message you will see that Facebook groups all the messages from username and displays on the page, well thats exactly what am trying to do over here.

Below is the code I have in place. Still trying to get something to work for me. Also screen shot of the current code example.

**SQL**

```
<?php
    $session_id = GET_SESSION_ID_VALUE(ENCRYPTION_KEY);
    $sql = "SELECT messages.*, profile.profile_id, profile.profile_name, profile.profile_photo, profile.profile_username FROM messages INNER JOIN profile ON profile.profile_id = messages.message_from WHERE messages.message_from = ' " . $session_id . "' OR messages.message_to = ' " . $session_id . "' ORDER BY messages.message_datetime DESC";
    $query = $db->SELECT($sql);
    if($db->NUM_ROWS() > 0){
        $rows = $db->FETCH_OBJECT();
        foreach($rows as $row){
            $message_id = $row->message_id;
            $message_from = $row->message_from;
            $message_content = $row->message_content;
            $message_content = (strlen($message_content) > 90) ? substr($message_content, 0, 100) . '...' : $message_content;
            $message_username = $row->profile_username;
            $message_name = $row->profile_name;                     
            $message_photo = $row->profile_photo;                       
        /* HTML GOES HERE */
        }
    }
    ?>
```

**Database table**

[image]

**Screenshot of the above code.**
[image]

Comment: Don't you just need to add who the message is from into the ORDER BY clause?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $session_id = GET_SESSION_ID_VALUE(ENCRYPTION_KEY);
    $sql = "SELECT messages.*, profile.profile_id, profile.profile_name, profile.profile_photo, profile.profile_username FROM messages INNER JOIN profile ON profile.profile_id = messages.message_from WHERE messages.message_from = ' " . $session_id . "' OR messages.message_to = ' " . $session_id . "' ORDER BY messages.message_datetime DESC";
    $query = $db->SELECT($sql);
    if($db->NUM_ROWS() > 0){
            $prevMessage_from=""; --Get name of previous message
            $rows = $db->FETCH_OBJECT();
            foreach($rows as $row){
            while ($prevMessage_from=$row->message_from)
             {--Here must be code that add messages to existing--}
            if ($prevMessage_from<>$row->message_from)
            {
            $message_id = $row->message_id;
            $message_from = $row->message_from;
            $message_content = $row->message_content;
            $message_content = (strlen($message_content) > 90) ? substr($message_content, 0, 100) . '...' : $message_content;
            $message_username = $row->profile_username;
            $message_name = $row->profile_name;                     
            $message_photo = $row->profile_photo;                       
            $prevMessage_from=$message_from;
            /* HTML GOES HERE */
            }

        }
    }
    ?>
```